# Choose one cell per row in data frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a vector that tells me, for each row in a date frame, the column index for which the value in this row should be updated.

```
> set.seed(12008); n <- 10000; d <- data.frame(c1=1:n, c2=2*(1:n), c3=3*(1:n))
> i <- sample.int(3, n, replace=TRUE)
> head(d); head(i)
  c1 c2 c3
1  1  2  3
2  2  4  6
3  3  6  9
4  4  8 12
5  5 10 15
6  6 12 18
[1] 3 2 2 3 2 1
```

This means that for rows 1 and 4, c3 should be updated; for rows 2, 3 and 5, c2 should be updated (among others). What is the cleanest way to achieve this in R using vectorized operations, i.e, without `apply` and friends? **EDIT:** And, if at all possible, without R loops?

I have thought about transforming `d` into a matrix and then address the matrix elements using an one-dimensional vector. But then I haven't found a clean way to compute the one-dimensional address from the row and column indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to first convert your data.frame to a matrix, you can index elements-to-be-replaced using a two-column matrix. (Beginning with `R-2.16.0`, this will be possible with data.frames directly.) The indexing matrix should have row indices in its first column and column indices in its second column.

Here's an example:

```
## Create a subset of the your data
set.seed(12008); n  <- 6 
D  <- data.frame(c1=1:n, c2=2*(1:n), c3=3*(1:n))
i <- seq_len(nrow(D))            # vector of row indices
j <- sample(3, n, replace=TRUE)  # vector of column indices 
ij <- cbind(i, j)                # a 2-column matrix to index a 2-D array 
                                 # (This extends smoothly to higher-D arrays.)  

## Convert it to a matrix    
Dmat <- as.matrix(D)

## Replace the elements indexed by 'ij'
Dmat[ij] <- NA
Dmat
#      c1 c2 c3
# [1,]  1  2 NA
# [2,]  2 NA  6
# [3,]  3 NA  9
# [4,]  4  8 NA
# [5,]  5 NA 15
# [6,] NA 12 18
```

---

Beginning with `R-2.16.0`, you will be able to use the same syntax for dataframes (i.e. without having to first convert dataframes to matrices).

From the `R-devel` `NEWS` file:

> Matrix indexing of dataframes by two column numeric indices is now supported for replacement as well as extraction.

Using the current `R-devel` snapshot, here's what that looks like:

```
D[ij] <- NA
D
#   c1 c2 c3
# 1  1  2 NA
# 2  2 NA  6
# 3  3 NA  9
# 4  4  8 NA
# 5  5 NA 15
# 6 NA 12 18
```

Comment: Has that been ported to the 2.15.1 branch? R-devel would usually mean the next minor version, i.e. 2.16.x.

Comment: @GavinSimpson -- Nice catch. Thanks. Looking again, I now see the prominent note that the "r59537 development snapshot of R [...] will eventually become R-2.16.0". Will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Will there be analogous support for matrices/arrays, too?

Comment: @user946850 -- There already is! Try this, to see how it works with arrays:  `a <- array(1:64, dim=c(4,4,4)); a[cbind(1:4, c(4,3,1,2), 1:4)] <- NA`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: Would you mind adding this as an answer in its own right, or perhaps edit this answer? This is much cleaner than what Gavin proposed, indeed. (Is there a reference to this kind of addressing in the docs?)

Comment: @user946850 -- Good idea. I've edited this post to demo both the currently available and the soon-to-be available options.

Answer (score 6):

With your example data, and using only the first few rows (`D` and `I` below) you can easily do what you want via a matrix as you surmise.

```
set.seed(12008)
n <- 10000
d <- data.frame(c1=1:n, c2=2*(1:n), c3=3*(1:n))
i <- sample.int(3, n, replace=TRUE)
## just work with small subset
D <- head(d)
I <- head(i)
```

First, convert `D` into a matrix:

```
dmat <- data.matrix(D)
```

Next compute the indices of the vector representation of the matrix corresponding to rows and columns indicated by `I`. For this, it is easy to generate the row indices as well as the column index (given by `I`) using `seq_along(I)` which in this simple example is the vector `1:6`. To compute the vector indices we can use:

```
(I - 1) * nrow(D) + seq_along(I)
```

where the first part ( `(I - 1) * nrow(D)` ) gives us the correct multiple of the number of rows (6 here) to index the start of the `I`th column. We then add on the row index to get the index for the n-th element in the `I`th column.

Using this we just index into `dmat` using `"["`, treating it like a vector. The replacement version of `"["` (`"[<-"`) allows us to do the replacement in a single line. Here I replace the indicated elements with `NA` to make it easier to see that the correct elements were identified:

```
> dmat
  c1 c2 c3
1  1  2  3
2  2  4  6
3  3  6  9
4  4  8 12
5  5 10 15
6  6 12 18
> dmat[(I - 1) * nrow(D) + seq_along(I)] <- NA
> dmat
  c1 c2 c3
1  1  2 NA
2  2 NA  6
3  3 NA  9
4  4  8 NA
5  5 NA 15
6 NA 12 18
```

Comment: Thank you. But is this construct `(I - 1) * nrow(D) + seq_along(I)` encapsulated in some function that is publicly accessible? (More general, I'm looking for something like `matrix.index(m, r, c)` where `r` is the row vector and `c` is the column vector. I know how to build it, but this must be in R core somewhere, no?) How does matrix addressing work internally?

Comment: No, it is not. `I` is the column (`c` in your notation), `seq_along(I)` is the row (or `r`). I used the things I did because of your example, though `i` is a vector as long as the number of rows according to your example so my code still works even for big `i`. For the last bit, study the C code or the R Internals documentations; it is all done in C, but note that as far as R is concerned, a matrix is just a vector with elements stacked columnwise, i.e. columns are filled first so when treating a matrix as a vector, all the rows of col 1 come first, then the rows of column 2 etc.

Comment: @user946850 That said, there is nothing stopping you writing a `matrixIndex()` using the example shown above. You can put that in your own private package and load it (or arrange for it to be loaded automagically) at the start of each R session.

Comment: @user946850 Why? This is a simple operation so easy to cook up. The R Core Development team have taken the stance that they want the core to be reasonably lean, so as to minimise the maintenance burden, or to include things that they want/need for their research etc. Code/functions in packages are first class R citizens, so there is no need to have everything in base R. Note that more complex indexing jobs (select the upper or lower triangles of a matrix) *are* included in base R, but not, as far as I know, the simple case you mention. It may well be in another package on CRAN?

Comment: Consistency. The way multi-dimensional indexes map to the storage is a design parameter, tightly coupled with the R core. What if this is ever changed? -- Other than that, indeed I agree that this can be in a separate package as well.

Comment: @user946850 if you want consistency, look elsewhere than R ;-) R is stable, so don't expect the external way matrices are indexed to change. Internally the code to do it will change but the code in my example will always work.

Comment: @user946850 & Gavin (+1) -- Looks like the R-core folks do see some utility in this, and have added it (well, its equivalent functionality) to the current R-devel. (More details in an answer I just added below).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
d[which(i == 1), "c1"] <- "one"
d[which(i == 2), "c2"] <- "two"
d[which(i == 3), "c3"] <- "three"

   c1  c2    c3
1   1   2 three
2   2 two     6
3   3 two     9
4   4   8 three
5   5 two    15
6 one  12    18
```

Comment: Thank you. This requires a loop over the columns, which isn't too bad. Still, is there a fully vectorized solution?